# Updating of a WPF Texblock fails after a number of iterations?

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I have a particular problem with updating a TextBlock with changing values (which will eventually be streamed over a network). This is a similar problem to that experienced by others on this forum with the exception that the test solution below works initially (i.e the timer successfully updates the textBlock1.text which then displays correctly) but then fails after a certain number of iterations (usually between 200 and 300).  I guess I am doing something wrong with whatever way I am handling the thread.

I am new to C#, .Net and threading so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace TestWPF_WorkerThreads
{
    MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int counter = 0;
        private string counterText="";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Timer myTimer = new Timer(Work, counterText, 1000, 100);

        }

        void Work(Object message)
        {
            counter++;
            counterText = counter.ToString();
            string temp = message.ToString();
            temp = temp + counterText;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            UpdateMessage(temp);
        }

        void UpdateMessage(string msg)
        {
            Action action = () => textBlock1.Text = msg;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(action);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a timer with a period of 100 milliseconds, and the code which it invokes contains a 'sleep' which waits 100 milliseconds. This sounds wrong!

You should read this [excellent article on timers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S3), you will see that the `System.Threading.Timer` which you are using continues to fire regardless of whether you 'sleep'. With WPF it is much better to use the `DispatcherTimer` class which fires on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ColinE that was really helpful! I read the article on MSDN and will check out the DispatcherTimer Class. 

In the meantime, having read the article, I was able to switch from the System.Threading.Timer class to the System.Timer.Timer class and make use of the Enabled property to ensure there was no conflict between the main thread and the worker thread. 
I am sure there is a better way of doing this (possibly through the DispatcherTimer Class as you suggest) but it has solved the problem for the moment.

Will post solution asap. Since I am a noob I have to wait for 8hrs

Answer (score 0):

Here's the adjusted program which continues to update the TextBlock successfully:

```
namespace TestWPF_WorkerThreads
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        private int counter = 0;
        private string counterText="";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                              // -- SOLUTION --
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10);               // Used a System.Timer.Timer Class
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Work);    // instead of the 
            aTimer.Enabled = true;                              // System.Threading.Timer Class

        }

        void Work(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = false;                             // and made use of the Enabled property to stop
            counter++;                          
            counterText = counter.ToString();   
            string temp = "Tick: ";             
            temp = temp + counterText;          
            Thread.Sleep(10);                   
            UpdateMessage(temp);               
            aTimer.Enabled = true;                              // and start the timer while the textBlock is updated
        }


        void UpdateMessage(string msg)
        {
            Action action = () => textBlock1.Text = msg;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(action);

        }
    }
}
```